# IIS Application Pool crashes when using Context.Server.Execute

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, application-pool

I am having an issue with an ASP.Net page I am writing and struggling to diagnose why this page is failing.

I am trying to do this:

```
  Dim st As New StringWriter()

  Dim strURL As String = "CourseProgramme.aspx?id=3733"
  Context.Server.Execute(strURL, st)
  txtNotes.Text = st.ToString()
```

The aim here is to get the HTML back for the page that has been specified in strURL and then display it in a textbox. However when I run this code it crashes the ApplicationPool in IIS and when I look in event viewer I see this error message:

> A process serving application pool 'blueprintdev' suffered a fatal
>   communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The
>   process id was '5284'. The data field contains the error number.

The strange thing here is that in another page I do this code which works fine:

```
  Dim strDutyStartDate As Date
  strDutyStartDate = TextboxDutyStartDate.Text

  Dim st As New StringWriter()
  Dim strURL As String = "rosteroutput.aspx?InstructorID=" & Request.QueryString("InstructorID") & "&Instructor=" & Request.QueryString("Instructor") & "&Start=" & strDutyStartDate

  Context.Server.Execute(strURL, st)
  TextBox1.Text = st.ToString
```

As far as I can see other than the URL I am passing, which does exist, I cannot see a difference between the two.

The page I am developing is in ASP.Net with .Net 4.0 however in the website there are some classic ASP pages. IIS is running at version 7.5.7600.16385 on Windows Server 2008 R2 64Bit.

So far I have tried setting the application pool to run in 32bit mode but that causes errors in other areas and the site will not load. Is there anything else I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you call this from him self :) do you make a close and run for ever loop ?

Comment: This is just called from a button click event. Not sure how it could go into a loop

Comment: Step over by making a break point on debugger and you find out how... oh, if you make it from the same page, on post back, then there is a second case that you fall into a dead mutex lock.

Comment: Create a NEW Request object and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

To make it an answer, what you probably do here is that somehow you trigger a non-stop loop.

For example, the call `Context.Server.Execute(strURL, st)` is trigger something that call again the `Context.Server.Execute(strURL, st)` and so on, so you crash your pool.

Second case, after your comment, if you call it from the same page, after button press and post back, then is very possible to fall into a dead mutex lock from the page, maybe the session, maybe something other.